# Trying to add color gradients to Matplotlib chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a red to green color gradient for my charts. When I run the the following however, I get:

```
TypeError: object of type 'Color' has no len()
```

Here is the piece of relevant code:

```
from colour import Color

red = Color("red")
colors = list(red.range_to(Color("green"),10))

for col in ['DISTINCT_COUNT', 'NULL_COUNT','MAX_COL_LENGTH', 'MIN_COL_LENGTH']: 
    grid[['COLUMN_NM', col]].set_index('COLUMN_NM').plot.bar(title=table_nm, figsize=(12, 8), color=colors)
    plt.xlabel('Column', labelpad=12)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

If I just run the top portion and print the results, it seems to run fine:

```
red = Color("red")
colors = list(red.range_to(Color("green"),10))
print(colors)

[<Color red>, <Color #f13600>, <Color #e36500>, <Color #d58e00>, <Color #c7b000>, <Color #a4b800>, <Color #72aa00>, <Color #459c00>, <Color #208e00>, <Color green>]
```

So it must be when I am trying to use it here:

```
grid[['COLUMN_NM', col]].set_index('COLUMN_NM').plot.bar(title=table_nm, figsize=(12, 8), color=colors)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: which statement causes error?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov  I added more details, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matplotlib cannot work with `colour.Color` instances. You may convert those to RGB values if you like.

Next, pandas does not like to be given several colors. But you may use a matplotlib plot instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from colour import Color

df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : list(range(3,13))})

red = Color("red")
colors = list(red.range_to(Color("green"),10))
colors = [color.rgb for color in colors]

plt.bar(df.index, df["x"], color=colors)
plt.xlabel('Column', labelpad=12)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that usually you would rather work with a colormap. You may call this colormap with the normalized values according to which you want to colorize your bars.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : np.random.rand(10)*10})

cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["red", "yellow", "green"])

plt.bar(df.index, df["x"], color=cmap(df.x.values/df.x.values.max()))
plt.xlabel('Column', labelpad=12)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works great.  I plugged in what you have into my code and I see all the colors represented across the columns.  The problem is they appear randomly, meaning there are tall bars that are solid red, short bars that are solid red... tall bars that are reddish/green and short bars that are the same tint etc.  Is there a way for them to change color based on the height/value of the bar itself across the graph?  The bars dont gradually go up as it goes to the right, as you have it. They are random sizes across.  If not that's ok, this is still better than solid blue for everything.

Comment: Sure, I mean all the examples you find use a colormap and then it is easy to get the respective colors for the bars. I updated the answer.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much for taking the time to write that out and explain it!